# Как правильно расставить знаки?

Tags: пунктуация, цитирование

*Сказал же: иди сюда!*

Или возможен вариант:

*Сказал же "иди сюда!"*

Или в предложении такого толка подобные цитаты не стоит выделять кавычками? А только посредством двоеточия или тире?

Answer (score 1):

Такие предложения обычно оформляются как бессоюзные сложные (без прямой речи и цитирования; ведь это слова одного и того же человека): [Я] *Сказал же,* [ты] *иди сюда.*

Обычное написание с запятой (пауза небольшая):
**Сказал же, иди сюда!**
*— Сказала же, иди своей дорогой* (Н. Дмитричев).
*— Сказал же, иди отсюда! Живо!* (В. Мокроусова)
*— Сказала же, иди рядом!* (К. Хигасино)

Для обозначения большей паузы чаще всего используется тире (реже — двоеточие):
**Сказал же — иди сюда!**
*— Сказал же — иди отсюда, — ответил продавец...* (А. Тамоников)
*— Сказала же — убирайся к чертям!* (Е. Ленская)